# Lazy preloading only some columns of relations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lazy-evaluation, preload

I'm currently using [ar_lazy_preload](https://github.com/DmitryTsepelev/ar_lazy_preload) Gem, for lazy preload, but sometimes I only need some attributes of those relations preloaded, I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve only some columns using select, maybe using Arel? (I'm not very familiar with it)

An example:
User - Person:  1 to 1 relation

User.lazy_preload(:person).all , but from person relation only need date of birth

the closest issue i found was [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/11erpxy/can_i_select_some_columns_from_preloaded_relations/) it does not work with ar_lazy_preload

I expect to lazy preload but with a query that uses a select to retrieve only what i need

`users = User.lazy_preload(person: [:date_of_birth]).all` making 1 queries

`Select * from users`  
`users.first.person.date_of_birth` makes another query

`Select people.date_of_birth from people where people.user_id in ($ids from first query)`